# filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: batch-file, makefile, nmake

when I am running this .bat file on command prompt it is throwing an error i.e "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect".

Batch file contains--

```
nmake /nologo /f makefile /a
pause
```

makefile contains the following:

```
# nmake makefile to build a sample ADK MAC compliant application 
# NOTE: EOSSDK is needed to resolve ADK Library references and header file includes  

VRXSDK = C:\eVoAps\SDK\1.2.0\VRXSDK
#VXEOS = C:\eVoAps\EOSSDK\2.1.4
ADK = C:\eVoAps\ADK
VSFSTOOL = C:\Program Files\VERIFONE\FST

VRXIncludes = $(VRXSDK)\include
ADKIncludes = $(ADK)\VRX\Include
EOSIncludes = $(EOSSDKNEW)\include\ssl2

IncDir = .\Source
SrcDir = .\Source
ObjDir = .\Objects
OutDir = .\Download

EOSObjects  = C:\eVoAps\SDK\1.2.0\EOSSDKNEW\lib
Includes = -I$(IncDir) -I$(VRXIncludes) -I$(EOSIncludes) -I$(ADKIncludes) -I$(SrcDir) 

# Compiler options 
# Ignoring warning 1295 - Deprecated declaration - give arg types
# Defiing _VRXEVO for Verix specific code in the sample.  
COptions = -vsoapp -g -p -armcc,"--diag_suppress 1295" -D _VRXEVO -DLOGAPI_ENABLE_DEBUG -DVFI_GUIPRT_IMPORT -DVFI_MAC_DLL_IMPORT -DVFI_IPC_DLL_IMPORT -DVFI_SYSINFO_DLL_IMPORT -DVFI_SYSBAR_DLL_IMPORT
LinkOptions = -vsoapp -g -p 

# NOTE: elog.o required to resolve references in the ADK libs.  Log lib requires STL
# LibVFIMac only needed to resolve sysShowDesktop()
# svc_net.o required for mac library....
Libs = $(ADK)\vrx\lib\libvfiguiprt.so \
    $(ADK)\vrx\lib\libvfiipc.so \
    $(ADK)\vrx\lib\liblog.so\
    $(ADK)\vrx\lib\libvfimac.so \
    $(VRXSDK)\lib\vxstl.so  \
    $(EOSSDKNEW)\lib\svc_net.o \
    $(EOSSDKNEW)\lib\elog.o 

AppObjects = $(ObjDir)\BossApp.o

$(OutDir)\BossApp.vsa.p7s : $(OutDir)\BossApp.vsa
    "$(VSFSTOOL)\FST" BossApp.fst

$(OutDir)\BossApp.vsa : $(AppObjects)
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxcc $(AppObjects) $(Libs) -o $@
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxhdr -s 128000 -h 128000 -l ELOG.LIB=N:/ELOG.LIB -l NET.LIB=N:/NET.LIB 
    $(OutDir)\BossApp.vsa

######  Compile #######
$(ObjDir)\BossApp.o : $(SrcDir)\BossApp.cpp
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxcc -c $(Includes) $(COptions) -o $(ObjDir)\BossApp.o $(SrcDir)\BossApp.cpp
```

I am unable to figure out what i'm missing here.Please help me.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to describe what you expect to happen and what the code actually does...

Comment: ...what language is this? It's not batch. It almost looks like somebody tried to write bash for Windows. Is it PowerShell?

Comment: this is makefile.  
batch file contains-- nmake /nologo /f makefile /a pause

Comment: The batch file works fine, it calls `nmake`. In your makefile is an error, but this is completely unrelated to batch files. It's always a good idea to debug code, to put some `echo` statements to surround the error

Comment: okk fine can u tell me what does this error mean?

Comment: Obviously somewhere is an error, you should find the line and output the variables there. Try a look at the help pages of `nmake` or search for `nmake verbose`

Answer (score 1):

This will likely be the reason for a very low % of people but I was getting this error from any .BAT file on my machine (happened to be Windows Server 2019). In my case I was getting the error because I had recently installed [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) (console replacement app) and had it set for Integration mode (where it replaces the normal CMD app) and it was failing to launch .BAT files correctly. Once I turned off Integration mode for ConEmu my .BAT files started working again.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure is not written in windows batch. It needs to be written in windows batch language to be processed by `cmd.exe`.

Comment: batch file contains--   nmake /nologo /f makefile /a
pause